# How to output all previous versions of a file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, version-history, csv, version

I have a script that displays multiple columns and outputs to CSV file below:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$url = "http://contoso.com"
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
$web = $site.OpenWeb()


function GetCheckedOutFiles($web)
{
Write-Host "Processing Web: $($web.Url)..."
        foreach ($list in ($web.Lists | ? {$_ -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPDocumentLibrary]})) {
            Write-Host "`tProcessing List: $($list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl)..."
            foreach ($item in $list.CheckedOutFiles) {
                #$modifiedTime = $web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone
                if (!$item.Url.EndsWith(".aspx")) { continue }
                $data = @{
                    #"URL"=$web.Site.MakeFullUrl("$($web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'))/$($item.Url)");
                     "Version" = $item["Version"]
                     "Title" = $item.Title
                     #"CheckedOut By" = $item.File.CheckedOutBy.Name
                     "#Time last Modified" = $modifiedTime.UTCToLocalTime($item.File.TimeLastModified)
                }
                New-Object PSObject -Property $data
            }
            foreach ($item in $list.Items) {

            #$modifiedTime = $web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone

            if ($item.File.CheckOutStatus -ne "None") {
                if (($list.CheckedOutFiles | where {$_.ListItemId -eq $item.ID}) -ne $null) { continue }


                $data = @{
                    #"URL"=$web.Site.MakeFullUrl("$($web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'))/$($item.Url)");
                    "Version" = $item["Version"]
                    "Library" = $item.Title
                    "Created By" = $item["Author"]
                    "Created Date" = $item["Created"]
                    "Modified By" = $item["Editor"]
                    "Modified Date" = $item["Modified"]
                    "Title" = $item.File.Name
                    #"CheckedOut By" = $item.File.CheckedOutBy.Name
                    #"Time last Modified" = $modifiedTime.UTCToLocalTime($item.File.TimeLastModified)
                }
                New-Object PSObject -Property $data
            }
        }

    }
foreach($subWeb in $web.Webs)
{
GetCheckedOutFiles($subweb)
}
        $web.Dispose()
}




GetCheckedOutFiles($web) | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\NewDocInventory.csv
```

Below is the part of the output and I'm mainly concerned with the Version column:

[image]

The Version column displays the current version of a file. Does anyone know how to get, in addition to the current version, all previous versions of the file. For example, FileA's current version is 12. I need to display version 12 all the way down to version 1 for this file. Can someone assist? I don't need links as I have been looking and no luck. Please advise with code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that adding `foreach($version in $item.Versions)` under `foreach($item in $list.Item)` and then adding `"Version" = $version.VersionLabel` under `$data = @{` does the trick.